# How can I automate the labeled in Serena Dimensions?

Tags: serena

I need to know how can I automate the labeled in Serena Dimensions, because I want to improve my work, and a idea is automate the labeled on it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by a label. In Dimensions there are projects/streams and baselines along with 'named branches' (single branch name for a stream, but many available for projects). You can set your defaults under Project | Preferences. If yoi have the privilege then you can create new branch names from the console usng the DVB command - e.g. DVB release_1.0 /desc="Release 1.0". Be careful to have a decent naming convention as branch names must be unique across all your products in your base database. They can be reused across projects though.